# How to update a model record? [Rails 4]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, view, controller

I need to update my `Pack` model in my Rails application, but every time I submit the form, nothing happens. Here's the code:

**packs_controller.rb**

```
  def edit
    @pack = Pack.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @pack = Pack.find(params[:id])
    if @pack.update_attributes(pack_params)
      flash[:success] = "Update successful!"
      redirect_to '/packs'
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

    def pack_params
      params.require(:pack).permit(:amount)
    end
```

**_edit_packs.html.haml**

```
= form_for(@pack) do |f|
    .form-group
        = f.label :amount
        = f.text_field :amount, :autofocus => true, class: 'form-control'
    = f.submit 'Submit', :class => 'button right'
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Here is the log when pressing submit:

```
Started PATCH "/packs/11" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-13 19:27:12 +0200
Started PATCH "/packs/11" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-13 19:27:12 +0200
Processing by PacksController#update as HTML
Processing by PacksController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"oa20eUeZPxbV+mX0mQyDyFibwWCnOlrtP/9uoKq2HU0=", "pack"=>{"amount"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"11"}
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"oa20eUeZPxbV+mX0mQyDyFibwWCnOlrtP/9uoKq2HU0=", "pack"=>{"amount"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "id"=>"11"}
  Pack Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "packs".* FROM "packs"  WHERE "packs"."id" = ?  ORDER BY created_on DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
  Pack Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "packs".* FROM "packs"  WHERE "packs"."id" = ?  ORDER BY created_on DESC LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Pack Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "packs"  WHERE ("packs"."created_on" = '2014-06-13' AND "packs"."id" != 11) LIMIT 1
  Pack Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "packs"  WHERE ("packs"."created_on" = '2014-06-13' AND "packs"."id" != 11) LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered packs/_edit_packs.html.haml (1.8ms)
  Rendered packs/_edit_packs.html.haml (1.8ms)
  Rendered packs/edit.html.haml within layouts/application (2.5ms)
  Rendered packs/edit.html.haml within layouts/application (2.5ms)
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 3  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 3  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.haml (1.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.haml (1.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.haml (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.haml (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 22.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 28ms (Views: 22.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.6ms)
```

**EDIT 2**

After having looked through some of the comments, and thinking about the problem, it seems like there's a problem with my uniqueness validation on the :created_on field, which stores the date the record was created on.

**EDIT 3**

Confirmed: :created_on is the root of the problem! I have a validation that enforces the uniqueness of :created_on. When I remove it, the form works. Here is my model:

**pack.rb**

```
class Pack < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    default_scope -> { order('created_on DESC') }
    scope :today, -> { where(:created_at => (Time.now.beginning_of_day..Time.now)) }
    scope :week, -> { where(:created_at => (Time.now.beginning_of_week..Time.now))}
    scope :month, -> { where(:created_at => (Time.now.beginning_of_month..Time.now))}
    scope :year, -> { where(:created_at => (Time.now.beginning_of_year..Time.now))}

    validates :user_id, presence: true
    validates :created_on, uniqueness: true
    validates :amount, presence: true, length: { maximum: 1 }
end
```

Any suggestions on how to get around this? Should I start a new question?

Comment: `but every time I submit the form, nothing happens.` something does happen. What page is being displayed?

Comment: Posting your `log information` when `submitting the form` would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you have any validation on `amount` field in `Pack` model?

Comment: Or any other validation if a Pack has more than just an amount

Comment: I think it's related to the .form-group and the fact that you are using haml, look at the generated html the submit button will not be in the form or remove the  .form-group (I can't confirm I'm on mobile)

Comment: @BroiSatse, it displays the edit page again (in other words, the changes aren't being saved). I meant that no record is being made. When it dsiplays the edit page again, the changes I made and submitted are indeed displayed in the new form, however, when I go back to the index, no change is registered.

Comment: @eXa I have other forms using haml and .form-group in which there are no problems.

Comment: @KirtiThorat I have a validation on :amount, enforcing for presence, and I have a validation on :created_on, enforcing for uniqueness.

Comment: @zenben1126 - This means that validation has failed. Inspect objects errors to find out why.

Comment: @zenben1126, can you post your Pack model here? It will help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your logs, it looks like you have multiple packs in your database that were `created_on` is equal to `'2014-06-13'` which will cause the created_on uniqueness validation to fail.

Check this in the rails console:

```
Pack.where(created_on: '2014-06-13')
```

If there is more than one, delete the extras and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to limit a pack to one per user per day you need to add a scope option to the created on validation:

```
validates :created_on, uniqueness: true, scope: user
```